# Can I subclass UIMenuController so that it can take icons instead of just text?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, ios4, uimenucontroller

How would one go about doing this?  I'm looking for a dense, purely graphical menu on tap-hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.2 you can add menu items using the `menuItems` property. But I think subclassing won't be useful, since it's a singleton that does not returns the views of each menu item. You could access `menuFrame` when `setMenuVisible:animated:` is called, so you can add you're own view that looks like a menu items with icons. But for adding icons to the system menu items... I think you should stick to what's Apple is giving you ;)

Answer (score 1):

*My low reputation don't let me post links, therefore I am answering again here:*

Check Emoji & Symbols, perhaps it will fit to your purpose.

Go to your Xcode Menu -> Edit -> Emoji & Symbols.

Ex.:

```
let menuItemYes = UIMenuItem(title: "✅", action: "doSomething")
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a category to support image for UIMenuItem. It's based on method swizzling, but should be safe in most cases.

https://github.com/cxa/CXAImageMenuItem

Note: duplicate answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14140904/395213

EDIT: the above link is 404'ed, this link works

https://github.com/cxa/UIMenuItem-CXAImageSupport