# Can UIMenuItem show UIImage?

Tags: ios5, uimenucontroller

I saw that it's possible — iBooks application does it.

Is it any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a category to support image for UIMenuItem. It's based on method swizzling, but should be safe in most cases.

https://github.com/cxa/UIMenuItem-CXAImageSupport

Comment: Can we also put an Image and some following text from your category?

Comment: Hi Cxa,  https://github.com/cxa/MenuItemKit works for iOS 10 but not for iOS 7, On compiling it shows minimum deployment target to be 8.0 and 
I want 7.0 too

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the current official API do that. UIMenuItem can only be initialised with -initWithTitle:action:

I suspect that Apple either using a private API or have implemented a custom control. Probably the former.

Asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414183/can-i-subclass-uimenucontroller-so-that-it-can-take-icons-instead-of-just-text)

Answer (score 1):

Check Emoji & Symbols, perhaps it will fit to your purpose.

Go to your Xcode Menu -> Edit -> Emoji & Symbols.

Ex.:

```
let menuItemYes = UIMenuItem(title: "✅", action: "doSomething")
```

Good luck!